# Error in varpart2, not same number of rows (despite same # of rows in data frame) -- Variation Partitioning

Tags: row, data-manipulation, na, vegan

I am working with a community ecology data set based around algal pigments and trying to understand what variables are driving changes in community composition/pigment concentrations. To answer this question, I plan on doing a variation partitioning approach to see which of my environmental drivers are most significantly influencing the changes in microalgae pigments. I am doing a test run with a limited data frame to see if this approach reveals anything notable/ it works.

I have my community structure data frame , benthiccc, and the two data frames that I'm treating as my x-variable matricies:
chemaxis = chemical sediment and h20 parameters that may be driving variation
phyaxis = physical parameters that my be driving variation

my code is:
`benthic_all_varpar <- varpart(benthiccc, chemaxis, physaxis)`

but returns the error:

```
Error in varpart2(Y, Sets[[1]], Sets[[2]], chisquare, permutations) : 
  Y and X1 do not have the same number of rows
```

When I look at the dataframes however, they have the same number of rows (333). Does this have to do with NA values? I have many rows (~100) that do not have fully complete data sets, and therefore have NA values. Is there anyway to work around this so that I don't loose over 100 data points because of their incompleteness? Many of the data points are missing only one parameter, and it would greatly weaken my strength to get rid of that many points.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Yes, the error is likely because of the NA values. Why are these values missing? Would it be reasonable to assume they are zero? If so, just replace them with zero prior to running `varpart`. If that assumption isn't reasonable then you could remove columns from chemaxis and physaxis that contain missing values, and carry out analysis just on the complete columns. Or you could consider removing rows with many missing values. Or you could try to impute the missing values - impute them as the mean or median or use packages like `mice` or `missForest`

Comment: You will get an error message with missing values, but quite a different error message. It is most natural to assume that message "Y and X1 do not have the same number of rows" means that Y and X1 do not have the same number of rows. You could start checking this: see what `nrow(benthiccc)` and `nrow(chemaxis)` return.